# Consume remotely located basic aspnet webservice using only html and jquery for mobile native app development

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-mobile

On one of our server we have hosted basic aspnet webservices. Other applications use this services and are able to get the result. Our requirement is to make native mobile app such that it can consume this aspnet webservice by using only html and jquery.

Found many solutions shown as html and webservice asmx file are in same project and has to be deployed on server, we don't require this since we want to develop native mobile app.

We have referred below article to access remote aspnet webservice,but it requires some configuration changes in web.config file of webservice which we are not planning to do.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP

Is there any alternative to JSONP? 
Other than html and jquery what more tools/library has to be used.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks and B'Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use HTML and jQuery, then I recommend you use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com).

PhoneGap allows you to deploy native apps to iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

As far as I know you should be able to do regular Ajax calls (without JSONP) using jQuery in PhoneGap.